# Mysql Query to select rows with or without dates

Tags: mysql, date, select

[image]

I want to select the rows based on today date with start and expiry date column and even rows which doesn't have date values. So

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discounts where '".date('Y-m-d')."' >= coupon_start_date AND '".date('Y-m-d')."' <= coupon_expiry_date
UNION SELECT * FROM ecwid_discounts where '".date('Y-m-d')."' >= coupon_start_date AND coupon_expiry_date is NULL union SELECT * FROM ecwid_discounts where coupon_start_date is NULL AND '".date('Y-m-d')."' <= coupon_expiry_date union SELECT * FROM ecwid_discounts where coupon_start_date is NULL AND coupon_expiry_date is null");
```

I would like to confirm if this query is correct or is there any better way of rewriting this query in short.

Any help guys

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You can use `OR` so you don't need `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discounts where '".date('Y-m-d')."' >= coupon_start_date AND '".date('Y-m-d')."' <= coupon_expiry_date
UNION SELECT * FROM ecwid_discounts where '".date('Y-m-d')."' >= coupon_start_date AND '".date('Y-m-d')."' <= coupon_expiry_date OR '".date('Y-m-d')."' >= coupon_start_date AND coupon_expiry_date is NULL OR coupon_start_date is NULL AND '".date('Y-m-d')."' <= coupon_expiry_date OR coupon_start_date is NULL AND coupon_expiry_date is null");
```